# How to install Arista transcoder from source?

Tags: installation, source-code

This package is not in Software Center. Official page offer only source files. How can I install this on 10.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *was* in the Software Centre.

```
$ apt-cache policy arista
arista:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.9.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.9.5-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe amd64 Packages
```

It's been a few years since this was first posted and it looks like Arista was abandoned, though they still run [its website](http://transcoder.org/downloads/index.html). If you still want it, you'll want to download the source from their github repo and continue below.

I can't guarantee it'll still work at all.

---

But to answer the actual question, you need to read the `README.md` file that's in the downloadable archive. It explains what dependencies you need. Moreover, it has an Ubuntu-specific install method available! Just run:

```
sudo python setup.py install --install-layout=deb
```

And it'll install. Just did this and it works fine. You might need to fetch the dependencies yourself (in the readme, again) but give it a go if you still can't find the `arista` package in the Software Centre

Comment: Thanks searched once again and found it version 0.9.3 in software center. Webpage offer version 0.9.5 So I'll going to install it from source.

Comment: If you upgraded Ubuntu to Maverick, you'd have access to the latest version in the repo :)

Comment: Now I have 0.9.5 on my 10.04 with one warning. UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'

Comment: Can not encode because these plugins are not installed. GStreamer-Element faac
GStreamer-Element x264enc

Comment: Checking on Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful). Arista is no longer in Software Center.

Comment: @mtnygard It's been abandoned for ~6 years. I suspect it was pulled because of that. The source is still available from their download page but I've updated the answer to reflect this.